# SignalR implementing CRUD methods in Hub or Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, signalr

I have an Angular app based on ASP.NET MVC application and there is a Dashboard where I display some of the Average and Total numbers that are changed in Create / Update / Delete events. Normally these events are implemented in the Controller as shown below:

***Controller.cs:***

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(Record record)
{
    // code omitted for brevity
    return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Update(Record record)
{
    // code omitted for brevity
    return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Delete(int id)
{
    // code omitted for brevity
    return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However, after each of execution of these methods, I need to call the corresponding Hub methods in order to update the numbers on the Dashboard page.

***Hub.cs:***

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public void Update(Record record)
    {
        Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);
    }
}
```

So, my questions are:

**1)** How can I combine these methods in order to update numbers on Dashboard page? Should I move the CRUD methods to the Hub and use only this methods like that? I added the last line in order to notify clients about the current statistics data.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Create(Record record)
{
    // code omitted for brevity
    return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    // send update to all clients
    Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);
}
```

Or should I keep the method in the Controller method and call hub method after the crud operation is executed?

**2)** As I update the statistics on the Dashboard page after a crud event, I think I build the structure different from chat app. Because I only send notification to the Dashboard component after crud event. Is that true?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a SignalR I recommend to use the CQRS architecture pattern. It will resolve your problems. In vertically sliced architecture you will see where will be the best spot to send notifications to all clients.

1) If you want a simple but smelled solution then do it this way. But I recommend using CQRS. 
2) yes :)

Comment: Thnaks a lot for these useful information. I have a look at CQRS, but currently we are not able to switch t use it as there are several people working on this project.

Comment: On the other hand, is there another smart solution without using CQRS instead of moving the CRUD methods to the Hub? Because as the the Hub class does not contain some methods that Controller class has, it would be better to continue to use the same method (Create Update Delete) in the Controller by adding `Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);` line after the operation is executed. Is it possible and could you please post an example?

Comment: When I create a record, normally I return the last added record by retrieving it via Entity Framework. On the other hand, I use a database view in order to update my Dashboard. So, I can modify my update view and include statistical data to it so that I can return both last added + statistical data to the related pages at the same time.

Comment: BUT, if I do so, I also need to update the other CRUD methods in order to return Dashboard data (statistical data). Instead of this, is it better to retrieve the last added record and statistics data separately and pass them corresponding View and Dashboard separately? Any idea?

Comment: If you return last added + statistical data then you don't need SignalR, because you send this synchronous in the HTTP response. In my opinion, a better approach is to send statistic data separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I do this? Should I retrieve Statistical data after create event in the Controller like that? First I create a new record, then I retrieve statistical data and then broadcast this statistical data via `Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);`. Finally return the data that I have already use on my Create page via `return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`. Is it true? Or what do you suggest?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: Yes, I thought about a solution like you described.

Comment: Many thanks again. In this scene, I think there is no need to modify the default Create method too much. Because simply adding an asynchronous method `Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);` after creating a new record (and before returning its result) will perform the SignalR job. Is this that true with using a async method for broadcast in the Controller method?

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best approach - do async call to `Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record);` and forgot about it.

Answer (score 1):

> On the other hand, is there another smart solution without using CQRS instead of moving the CRUD methods to the Hub? Because as the the Hub class does not contain some methods that Controller class has, it would be better to continue to use the same method (Create Update Delete) in the Controller by adding Clients.All.updateStatisticsToPage(record); line after the operation is executed. Is it possible and could you please post an example?

I didn't use it this in that way but I think it is possible. You could try to create StatisticsHub with IStatisticsHub interface:

```
public interface IStatisticsHub
{
    Task Send(string message);
}

public class StatisticHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub, IStatisticsHub
{
    private readonly IHubContext<StatisticHub > _context;

    public StatisticHub(IHubContext<EventTypeHub> context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task Send(string message)
    {
        await _context.Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", message);
    }
}
```

Now you can add this hub to DI container as Singleton:

```
services.AddSingleton<IStatisticsHub, StatisticHub>();
```

The last step is to inject this hub into your controller:

```
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStatisticsHub _statisticsHub;

    public Controller(IStatisticsHub statisticsHub)
    {
        _statisticsHub = statisticsHub;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Update(Record record)
    {
        // code omitted for brevity

        // send message to all clients
        _statisticsHub.Send("Statistics");

        return Json(new { Data = data, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
}
```

It should be working in that way.

First of all, the frontend has to create a WebSocket connection with this hub to receives all messages, but I believe you already know it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try to apply this approach and inform you besides marking as answer this. For now of course voted up x 2 ;)

Comment: Dear Beniamin, many thanks for your helps. Now I am improving my code on Hub and Controller side and think of that using the approach above.

Comment: But normally I used the following approach (just look at Hub and Controller part) on [Transform An Existing MVC App To A Real-Time App Using SignalR](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/transform-an-existing-mvc-app-to-a-real-time-app-using-signalr/). There is no DI there, but I am not sure what is the difference between this code and your code of Hub & Controller? This code does not use DI, I know, but use static method and simply calls it. Any idea about pros and cons?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: With DI you can easily test your code (easily mock all dependencies and create unit tests for methods in your controller.). If you're using static objects in your methods then creating unit tests is impossible (you cannot mock static classes).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when trying to apply this approach I encountered some errors i.e. "*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'JiraHub.BroadcastData(JsonResult)'*" and I think it is due to that I use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;` in my ASPNET MVC project. So, in this case shall I apply the approach on [Strongly typed hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#strongly-typed-hubs)? What do you suggest in order to use Strongly typed hubs in my ASPNET MVC project?